# "Terms dictionary" or "Term dictionary"

Tags: grammatical-number

On the one side a dictionary contains many terms, on the other one a dictionary is a single book (or website, whatever).

I am not sure which form is correct

Maybe I should not use "Term" instead of "Terminology"?

Comment: Are you aware of any dictionaries that *don't* contain many terms?

Comment: Most **terminological dictionaries** are devoted to the terminology of one specific field, being called things like _Dictionary of Medical Terminology_ or _Dictionary of Legal Terms_. You won’t find any dictionaries out there that are just generic ‘terminology dictionaries’. If you’re looking for a generic noun to describe this _type_ of dictionary (as opposed to regular dictionaries who deal with the language in its entirety), there’s a hint in the first line of this comment that tells you what they’re normally called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be best to simply say ***Dictionary***. If you really wanted to be more verbose, a common expansion is ***Dictionary of Terms*** or ***Glossary of Terms***.

Incidentally, *Term Dictionary* makes me think of a dictionary that is used in school for one semester.